# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) when UrhoSurface.OnDestroy() is called

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, sdl, urhosharp

I am developing an android app Using UrhoSharp. I have created a SDLSurface as;

```
surface = UrhoSurface.CreateSurface (this, typeof(UrhoLayer), appOptions);
```

When I press back button the app crashes after some time. The app seems to crash only when UrhoSurface.OnDestroy() is called.  Here is the stacktrace;

```
[SDL] onDestroy()
[SDL] nativeQuit()
[Mono] [0x7192d4d8] hill climbing, change max number of threads 126
[Mono] DllImport searching in: 'mono-urho' ('libmono-urho.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'TryDeleteRefCounted'.
[Mono] Probing 'TryDeleteRefCounted'.
[Mono] Found as 'TryDeleteRefCounted'.
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
[Mono] GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 1519 num_hash_entries 1762 sccs size 1762 init 0.00ms df1 5.28ms sort 3.72ms dfs2 1.98ms setup-cb 1.65ms free-data 5.77ms links 421/421/1071/17 dfs passes 3702/2183
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (user request) pause 41.87ms, total 44.04ms, bridge 0.03ms major 1904K/0K los 180K/0K
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #15
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #16
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #17
[Mono] [0x6e635b30] worker starting
[Mono] [0x6d788a28] worker starting
[Mono] [0x701cf728] worker starting
[Mono] GC_OLD_BRIDGE num-objects 443 num_hash_entries 620 sccs size 620 init 0.00ms df1 3.39ms sort 0.43ms dfs2 1.86ms setup-cb 0.67ms free-data 1.19ms links 319/319/969/17 dfs passes 1382/939
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (user request) pause 25.58ms, total 25.76ms, bridge 0.00ms major 1808K/0K los 180K/0K
[Mono] DllImport searching in: 'mono-urho' ('libmono-urho.so').
[Mono] Searching for 'RefCounted_ReleaseRef'.
[Mono] Probing 'RefCounted_ReleaseRef'.
[Mono] Found as 'RefCounted_ReleaseRef'.
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] Attempting native Android stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at ???+132 [0x597f3084]
[mono-rt]   at ???+16380 [0x597f2ffc]
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x597f3084 (code=2), thread 2835 (SDLThread)
```

Comment: You should look at your tombstone (the longer stacktrace) and see if you find any valuable information about it. Informations about tombstone: http://bytesthink.com/blog/?p=133

Comment: @Santosh, which version of Urho do you use?

Comment: @Nagg, I use version 1.0.500.